# i want to use the build index in an if else statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im pretty new to C#, im getting an error (10,35): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string' but i dont know how to fix it. i want change if the cursor is visible or not based on what scnene is active

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Cursorhide : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    void Update()
    {
        if(SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex < 1))
        {
         Cursor.visible = true;
        }
         else
        {
         Cursor.visible = false;
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? While you might feel it's obvious, it's still necessary to point it out in your question so that there's no misunderstanding.

Comment: I suspect `LoadScene` expects a screen name but gets the result of `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex < 1`, a boolean expression.

Comment: [`LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) expects either an integer or a string.  You're passing it a boolean.  (Well, an expression which is a comparison operation which resolves to a boolean to pass to the method.)  What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 0):

`LoadScene` expects a string, like `LoadScene("mainMenu")`

you put `...index < 1` in it. This evaluates to a boolean: true/false.

Not sure what your goal is, but you can do this:

```
if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex < 1))
    {
     Cursor.visible = true;
    }
```

- Maybe the `LoadScene` was auto-completed by accident? Otherwise, please clarify your goal.

Comment: i want to turn off/on the cursor based on what scene is active